# Probability of C after event A and B have occured

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

**Event A:**
Cardiac arrest

**Event B:**
Death of cardiac arrest

Assuming $1$ in $1000$ heat-strokes lead to a cardiac arrest (**A**)

$1$ in $100$ cardiac arrests lead to death (**B**)

What is the probability of cardiac arrest leading to death due to a heat stroke (**C**) ?

[I was thinking this formula applies:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHOXg.png)

I calculated $0.01$ ($A$ and $B$) / $0.001$ (**A**).
The result is $10$ which cannot be correct.

Where lies my mistake / thinking error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's much more intuitive than that. If $1$ in $1000$ heat strokes lead to a cardiac arrest, the probability of cardiac arrest due to a heat stroke is $0.001$. Similarly, the probability of death after a cardiac arrest is $0.01$. Since **A** and **B** are independent events, the probabilities multiply. So the probability of the event "*cardiac arrest leading to death due to a heat stroke*" is

$$
0.001\times0.01 = 0.00001.
$$

Comment: Thanks Klangen. Could you help me understand why they are independent events ? In the example, event B only occurs if event A has happened. Why are they then considered independent ? 

Is the definition something like:
If event X can "generally" occur by itself it is considered independent ?

Comment: sorry, no need to answer my comment. I think I got it. It's clear that both events can happen independently from one another.

Comment: @natzer Independence is by definition having the *probability of a heat stroke leading to death by cardiac arrest* is equal to the *probability of a heat stroke leading to cardiac arrest* multiplied by the *probability of a cardiac arrest causing death*.  There is no particular reason to suppose these are independent: cardiac arrests caused by heat strokes may be more or less dangerous than other cardiac arrests